# long pulling if record is new

Tags: php, javascript, long-polling

i have one table in my db.

```
Employee
___________________________________
| Name      |   City              |    
___________________________________
| Jack      |  UK                 |
___________________________________
| John      |  Kenya              |
___________________________________
```

and i am use select query to get value from this table.
this is my sql.php file for select data from Employee.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","company");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM employee");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['name'] . "&nbsp" . $row['city'];
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and now i am try long pulling this is simple code of long pulling:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BargePoller</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body{ background:#000;color:#fff;font-size:.9em; }
      .msg{ background:#aaa;padding:.2em; border-bottom:1px #000 solid}
      .old{ background-color:#246499;}
      .new{ background-color:#3B9957;}
    .error{ background-color:#992E36;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function addmsg(type, msg){
        /* Simple helper to add a div.
        type is the name of a CSS class (old/new/error).
        msg is the contents of the div */
        $("#messages").append(
            "<div class='msg "+ type +"'>"+ msg +"</div>"
        );
    }

    function waitForMsg(){
        /* This requests the url "msgsrv.php"
        When it complete (or errors)*/
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "sql.php",

            async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
            cache: false,
            timeout:1000, /* Timeout in ms */

            success: function(data){ /* called when request to barge.php completes */
                addmsg("new", data); /* Add response to a .msg div (with the "new" class)*/
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Request next message */
                    1000 /* ..after 1 seconds */
                );
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Try again after.. */
                    1000); /* milliseconds (15seconds) */
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        waitForMsg(); /* Start the inital request */
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="messages">
        <div class="msg old">
            BargePoll message requester!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

its work perfect and ajax call every second.
but i want to set if any changes are made in table then its append div on my page other wise nothing. 
how can i do this.
thanks.

Comment: How is an Ajax request every second "long polling"? It's just "polling".

Answer (score 1):

You should increment the polling interval from 1 sec to something like 15 seconds and you are fine.

---

A real notification system - like on StackExchange- would require a [web socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) based solution. Additionally you'll need some stored procedures in mysql - registered as trigger functions - which can communicate with the web socket server.